# Ext js4 gauge chart and setValue

Tags: charts, extjs4, setvalue, gauge

I'm trying to setup a gauge chart in extjs 4 that should be feeded from a "static" value calculated from data.Store data.

The calculated data is obtained in a datachange listener in the store.

I read about the setValue method but i really did not understand how to use it, can anyone give me some hint?

Thanks to all,
N

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head to the wall for some hours, I just found out how it works. And it was oh so obvious:

```
// the value that you want to set up
var newValue = 35;
// a reference to the chart
var chart = Ext.getCmp('myChartId');
// setting the value
chart.series.items[0].setValue(newValue)
```

Notice that `setValue` is within `chart.series.items[0]`. This is because, as conter-intuitive as it may sound, ***Gauge* is NOT a type of chart** but **a type of series**.

Hope this helps other newbies of Ext like me, because the documentation could really use some more examples!